# spring security + spring boot mvc index page before authentication looks like bare html

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-security

Before auth

[image: pic 1]

After i log in by any account

[image: pic 2]

Does anyone know what's the matter? No clue.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Three is currently too little information to give you an answer. Please add the afformentioned page as well as your configuration. Please add them as text and use the proper code tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved!

I created class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

This way, I say /static/** if any page request by this prefix, so try to find in classpath:static

In my index thymeleaf file i including external css file by:

```
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{static/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This example above is shows how to add route where is app should find static resources, but this not necessary actually in my project.

The thing is when you trying to access to static resources before you logged in, you should give the permission to it in WebSecurityConfig class, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/login","/css/**", "/webjars/**", "/images/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/subscribers", "/calldetails").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/divisions").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
```

Comment: Glad you made it working. I was hitting right . it was annotations that I missed to add

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your css is not loading for unsecured context. For adding the resources make resource handler entry as below in WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern(URL_PATTERN_UICONTENT)) {
            registry.addResourceHandler(URL_PATTERN_UICONTENT).addResourceLocations("classpath:/uicontent/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
            registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I create new class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. And it says it's deprecated extend. Where i should put this code on?

Comment: Your new class should 'implements WebMvcConfigurer' not 'extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter'. Also i believe you have configured the template engine and place your static resources as expected.

Comment: There's no class if i impelement WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but there is WebMvcConfigurer. May be you mean that? But also i add this class, trying to use ur code. But my mapping in controllers don't work, i can't access to any of page.  resources/static - css.      resources/templates - my themyleaf pages.

Comment: Yes, i meant 'WebMvcConfigurer'. Can you share your HTML file and project structure.

Comment: Thanks for the git repo, i am working on it and will provide resolution soon